# BJP5 Exercise 16.7: deleteBack — Help me understand the solution

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have been working on this exercise to practice `ListNode`s, and was very frustrated because even though I thought I wrote the code correctly (as shown below), it didn't let me pass.

```java
public int deleteBack()
{
    ListNode p = front;
    if(p == null)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
    }

    if(p.next == null)
    {
        int data =  p.data;
        p = null; 
        return data;
    }

    while(p.next.next != null)
    {
        p = p.next;
    }
    int data = p.next.data;
    p.next = null;
    return data;
}
```

Next, I tried creating in total three new `ListNode`s equal to `front`. Although, I didn't quite see why this would be necessary.

```java
public int deleteBack()
{
    ListNode p = front;
    if(p == null)
    {
        throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
    }

    ListNode q = front;
    if(q.next == null)
    {
        int data =  q.data;
        q = null; 
        return data;
    }

    ListNode r = front;
    while(r.next.next != null)
    {
        r = r.next;
    }
    int data = r.next.data;
    r.next = null;
    return data;
}
```

Unfortunately, that also gave me the same result as before (passing only three tests), until I changed `q = null` to `front = null`. After this change, all tests were passed.

What I'm trying to understand is

- why my original code—which seems fine to me—doesn't work.
- why I had to create more than one `ListNode` equal to `front`.
- why I had to set `front = null` instead of `q = null`.

I'm far from being satisfied. Could someone help me understand why these changes were necessary?

Comment: Where does front come? It looks like a global / class variable, and I guess changing its copies (p, q...) to null is indeed not the same at all as changing front!

Comment: front is a private ListNode: https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/bjp5/chapter16/e7-deleteBack

Comment: "front;   // null for an empty list" has to be respected! (I guess)

Comment: Then why does it work when I set r.next = null rather than front = null?

Comment: because in that 3rd case of your code the full list is not empty, which happens only in the 2nd case !? Cf you removed only one element, but there were others in front of it

Comment: in that 3rd case, front = null would "delete" the full list, which would be wrong

Answer (score 0):

https://practiceit.cs.washington.edu/problem/view/bjp5/chapter16/e7-deleteBack
asks that `private ListNode front;   // null for an empty list`

In your first case, front is already null (as its copy p is).
In your second case, you remove the last and only one value in the list, so front must become null as the list is now empty. Setting the local copy q to null doesn't take care of that.
In your 3rd case, there were more than 1 element in the list, so after removing the last element the list is not empty, and front must keep its not null value.