# What does mean this section of Remove List Node in C mean

Tags: c, list, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Below is the complete code to Delete the last Node of a linked simple List and if it works well The function is void deleteLastNode ().

But exactly what does this part mean? It seems to me to spare because when the while loop ends we have the toDelete node in the last place and secondLastNode as the penultimate.

```
if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
```

THE deleteLastNode () FUNCTION IS THIS:

```
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
        }

        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}
```

BUT I BELIEVE THIS IS SUFFICIENT:

```
/*  */
void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }





            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;


        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}
```

The complete code is this: and the function is void deleteLastNode () ::

```
/**
 * C program to delete last node of Singly Linked List
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/* Structure of a node */
struct node {
    int data;          // Data
    struct node *next; // Address 
}*head;

void createList(int n);
void deleteLastNode();
void displayList();


int main()
{
    int n, choice;

    /*
     * Create a singly linked list of n nodes
     */
    printf("Enter the total number of nodes: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    createList(n);

    printf("\nData in the list \n");
    displayList();

    printf("\nPress 1 to delete last node: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    /* Delete last node from list */
    if(choice == 1)
        deleteLastNode();

    printf("\nData in the list \n");
    displayList();

    return 0;
}


/*
 * Create a list of n nodes
 */
void createList(int n)
{
    struct node *newNode, *temp;
    int data, i;

    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    /*
     * If unable to allocate memory for head node
     */
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
    }
    else
    {
        /*
         * Input data of node from the user
         */
        printf("Enter the data of node 1: ");
        scanf("%d", &data);

        head->data = data; // Link the data field with data
        head->next = NULL; // Link the address field to NULL

        temp = head;

        /*
         * Create n nodes and adds to linked list
         */
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            newNode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

            /* If memory is not allocated for newNode */
            if(newNode == NULL)
            {
                printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Enter the data of node %d: ", i);
                scanf("%d", &data);

                newNode->data = data; // Link the data field of newNode with data
                newNode->next = NULL; // Link the address field of newNode with NULL

                temp->next = newNode; // Link previous node i.e. temp to the newNode
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }

        printf("SINGLY LINKED LIST CREATED SUCCESSFULLY\n");
    }
}


/*
 * Delete last node of the linked list
 */

void deleteLastNode()
{
    struct node *toDelete, *secondLastNode;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is already empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        toDelete = head;
        secondLastNode = head;

        /* Traverse to the last node of the list */
        while(toDelete->next != NULL)
        {
            secondLastNode = toDelete;
            toDelete = toDelete->next;
        }

        if(toDelete == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Disconnect link of second last node with last node */
            secondLastNode->next = NULL;
        }

        /* Delete the last node */
        free(toDelete);

        printf("SUCCESSFULLY DELETED LAST NODE OF LIST\n");
    }
}


/*
 * Display entire list
 */
void displayList()
{
    struct node *temp;

    /*
     * If the list is empty i.e. head = NULL
     */
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("List is empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while(temp != NULL)
        {
            printf("Data = %d\n", temp->data); // Print the data of current node
            temp = temp->next;                // Move to next node
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58847642/bjp5-exercise-16-7-deleteback-help-me-understand-the-solution?noredirect=1#comment103969009_58847642 was pretty much the same question, you do need to correct the head value

Answer (score 0):

In the second function implementation if the last node is the head node then the variable head itself is not changed. So the function can have undefined behavior when the list contains only one node that is the head node.

Pay attention to that in any case the function implementation is bad. For example the function deals with the global variable head. So within a program you can not define two lists.

The function can be written much simpler.

```
void deleteLastNode( struct node **head )
{
    if ( *head != NULL )
    {
        while ( ( *head )->next != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        free( *head );

        *head = NULL;
    }
}
```

and called like

```
deleteLastNode( &head );
```